# Trying to prove Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder following these steps

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I know a proof for this theorem is a recurrent issue but I've checked wikipedia's proof and several posts in this forum about it and even if I found some similarities I couldn' solve my problem.

Let $X$ be a set with an injection $h:X \to X$ and $Y$ a subset such that $h(X) \subset Y \subset X$. The goal is to prove there's a bijection between $Y$ and $X$ following these steps:

$(1)$ Prove there exists a minimal subset $Z \subset X$ such that $(X-Y)\subset Z$ and $h(Z)\subset Z$

$(2)$ Prove that $h(Z)=Z\cap Y$

$(3)$ Using the injective function $h$ and the subset $Z\subset X$ defined in $(1)$ construct a bijective function $h':X\to Y$

$(4)$ Prove, using the steps above, that if $A$ and $B$ are sets such that there exist two injections $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$, then there is a bijection between those sets.

.

This is what I've done:

$(1)$ Let $I=\lbrace V\subset X | (X-Y) \subset V \land h(V) \subset V \rbrace$ and define  $Z=\bigcap_{V\in I} V$ It can be proven that $Z$ satisfies all the conditions required (I omit the details but if someone asks me to I will write them) and in addition $Z$ is not empty.

$(2)$ Here is where I'm stuck. It is clear that $h(Z)\subset Z$ by definition and because of $h(X)\subset Y$ then $h(Z)\subset Y$,so one of the inclusion is obvious but I can't prove the other one. I've tryed assuming there is some $x\in Z\cap Y$ which is not in $h(Z)$ but I didn't find any contradiction under this assumption (which is what I'm needing) Perhaps reductio ad absurdum is not the right way to get it, any advise on this point would be greatly appreciated.

$(3)$ Let $h':X\to Y$ be defined as follows: $$h'(x)=h(x) \ \mbox{if $x \in Z$} \\ h'(x)=x \ \mbox{if $x \not\in Z$}$$ Again I omit the details but it can be proven that $h'$ is a bijection.

$(4)$ Finally, here i tryed to "emulate" what I've done in the steps before. So, if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are injections and I let $I= \lbrace V \subset A| (A-g(B)) \subset V \land f(V) \subset g^{-1}(V) \rbrace$, then I define $Z=\bigcap_{V\in I}V$ but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is useful, it seems to me that I should prove that $Z\in I$ and $f(Z)=g^{-1}(Z)$ and then define some function $t:A\to B$ (hopefully bijective). I tryed defining it this way: $$t(x)=f(x) \ \mbox{if $x \in Z$} \\ t(x)=g^{-1}(x) \ \mbox{if $x \not\in Z$}$$ But I don't feel completly confident with it, I think something is not working with this function I've defined.

.

Any guiding idea, advice or attempts to solve would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: There are other proofs of this theorem. One in particular (attributed to Julius Konig) that is short and simple. See Schroder- Bernstein Theorem in Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad (2). Let $W=(X-Y)\cup h(Z)\subset Z.$ Since $h(W)\subset h(Z)\subset W$ and $X-Y\subset W,$ we have $W\in I,$ whence $W=Z$ and $Z\cap Y=W\cap Y=h(Z).$

Ad (4). Let $X=A,$ $Y=g(B),$ and $h=gf,$ so that $Y\subset X$ and $h:X\to Y$ is an injection. By the previous result there is a bijection from $X$ to $Y,$ i.e., a bijection from $A$ to $g(B);$ compose this with $g^{-1}$ to get a bijection from $A$ to $B.$

Comment: Hi @bof, your approach to prove $h(Z)=Z\cap Y$ is elegant, but I fell that is is not quite intuitive. It is easy to prove $h(Z) \subset (Z\cap Y)$. Is there any intuitive way to prove $h(Z) \supset (Z\cap Y)$?

Comment: @DungLe I'm not sure I agree that the argument I gave is unintuitive, but perhaps you will prefer the following. Note that $$Z=Z_0\cup Z_1\cup Z_2\cup\cdots$$ where $Z_0=X-Y$ and $Z_{n+1}=h(Z_n).$ Then $$h(Z)=Z_1\cup Z_2\cup Z_3\cup\cdots=Z-Z_0=Z-(X-Y)=Z\cap Y.$$

Comment: Hi @bof, I possibly find a way to prove $(Z\cap Y) \subset h(Z)$ as follows. Assume $(Z\cap Y) \not\subset h(Z) \implies \exists p\in (Z\cap Y)$ such that $p \notin h(Z) \implies p \in Y$. Let $W=Z-\{p\}$. First,$p \in Y \wedge X-Y\subset Z \implies X-Y \subset Z-\{p\} \implies X-Y \subset W$. Second, $h(W)=h(Z-\{p\})=h(Z)-h(\{p\})\subset h(Z) \subset h(Z)-\{p\}$ [Since $p \notin h(Z)$] $\subset Z-\{p\}$ [Since $h(Z) \subset Z$]$=W$. So, we have $X-Y \subset W$ and $h(W)\subset W$, then $W \in I$, but $W \subsetneq Z$. This contradicts to the minimality of $Z$. Thus $ (Z \cap Y) \subset h(Z)$.

Comment: Please check my above reasoning @bof!

Comment: @DungLe I answer questions on this site for fun. Checking other people's work is no fun. It's too much like grading test papers.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your previous comment! It gave me new useful insights.